# Como manejar en una tabla un evento de selección de una filas cargadas con datos mapeados de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Tengo una tabla que es cargada con datos de un API
He cargado en el  los datos exitosamente pero ahora deseo manejar una selección de la fila que desee elegir el usuario.

Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: No es claro lo que preguntas, ¿A qué te refieres con manejar una selección de fila? y sobre todo hay que incluir código de lo que se lleva hecho hasta ahora y que has intentado para solucionar tu problema

Comment: @Yikarus con la descripción del problema creo que el código es lo más común ya que puede ser cargada la información por medio de un arreglo de objetos con x información, que luego se carga con un map en la tabla. He intentado utilizar evento onClick en un botón insertado en la última columna de la tabla que tome la información de acuerdo al índice del arreglo en el que este posicionado, pero debo seguir revisándolo porque no está funcionando bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar un evento click en `jquery` y obtener el valor del `tr` y hacerle un `each` a los td para obtener su valor seria algo asi

```
$("#table").on("click","tr",function(){
  var valores = []
  $(this).find("td").each(function(){
    valores.push(this.html())
  })
})
```

sin jquery

obtenemos el `event` y el tr al que le hicieron click despues sus hijos y a cada hijo lo iteramos con el for haciendo push a un nuevo arreglo de solo los valores del tr seleccionado

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1")

table.addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData(){
var tds = event.path[1].children
 var datos = []
 for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  datos.push(tds[i].innerText)
 }
 console.log(datos);
}
```

Comment: Y tal vez alguna otra opción que no use jQuery..??

Comment: ya le agregue con javascript vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera. 
Estoy usando ReactJs y he cargado datos de mi API en una tabla, en el tbody. Cada td tiene un objeto y la última columna del td he colocado un  que tiene evento onClick que primero recoge como parámetro el event que luego lo apagare con un preventDefault() para luego recoger objeto.clave esto resuelve la selección de la fila y que deseo hacer con la fila. Gracias a todos por ver mi pregunta y aportar.
No opte por las soluciones en jQuery o JS Vanilla porque estoy usando ReactJs y me pareció mas fácil tomar la selección de la fila con lo habitual. Saludos

Comment: exelente amigo en la proxima duda que tengas por favor especifica el lenguaje o libreria en que estas trabajando para darte una solucion acorde al problema

Comment: Hola.. creo para eso están las etiquetas... No creí necesario por eso

Comment: disculpa me refiero al codigo como tal para revisarlo y darte una solucion

Comment: A claro... Lo subiré al github la próxima... Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo, aprovecha las propiedades del objeto que construye la fila:

```
// Creas el manejador del evento
handleRowSelection(e) {
    alert(e);
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
        {filas.map(f =>
          <tr key={f.id}>
            ...
            <td>
              <!-- Al hacer bind sobre un evento y pasarle parámetros más que el this,
                   el handler (manejador) tomará como parámetros todo lo demás. -->
              <button onClick={this.handleRowSelection.bind(this, f.id)}>
                Seleccionar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )}
        ...
    );
}
```